# Adding quotes around a date variable at run time - SQL / PL-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using this line in my PL-SQL procedure script:

```
l_query := REPLACE(l_query,'<REF_D>',  REF_D)
```

this results in:

```
select sum(rec_count) from mt_table_status where table_id = 8942 and ref_d = 15.06.17
```

but SQL is not executing it because the REF_D is not in inverted commas ('')

How do I enclose my date variable in quotes?

P.S. I have tried QUOTENAME but I get an error saying:

> identifier quotename must be declared

As always.. any help is much appreciated..

Comment: The question is not that clear; what should the resulting string be? Also, it seems that you're using dynamic SQL, so why not using bind variables?

Comment: Why do you use string for DATE values?

Comment: @Aleksej: Thanks a lot man.. didnt know what bind variables are..:) but your idea about dynamic sql helped..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you have some dynamic SQL that you want to modify to use a variable value as a filter.

Assuming that you can not edit your query, this is a way to handle double quotes while replacing the placeholder with the variable value; for example:

```
declare
    vSQL    varchar2(100);
    vVar    varchar2(10);
    vNum    number;
begin    
    vSQL := 'select count(*) from dual where ''a'' = <SOME_VAR>';
    vVar := 'a';
    --
    vSQL := replace (vSQL, '<SOME_VAR>', '''' || vVar || '''');
    execute immediate vSQL into vNum;
    dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || vNum);
end;
```

If you could edit your dynamic SQL, a better way could be handling the double quotes in the SQL part instead of doing it in the variable substitution part; for example:

```
declare
    vSQL    varchar2(100);
    vVar    varchar2(10);
    vNum    number;
begin    
    vSQL := 'select count(*) from dual where ''a'' = ''<SOME_VAR>''';
    vVar := 'a';
    --
    vSQL := replace (vSQL, '<SOME_VAR>', vVar);
    execute immediate vSQL into vNum;
    dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || vNum);
end;
```

Another way ( the best one IMHO) could be by using a bind variable; for example:

```
declare
    vSQL    varchar2(100);
    vVar    varchar2(10);
    vNum    number;
begin    
    vSQL := 'select count(*) from dual where ''a'' = :SOME_VAR';
    vVar := 'a';
    --
    execute immediate vSQL into vNum using vVar;
    dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || vNum);
end;
```

This assumes that your data types are strings, even if it seems that you could need dates; if you have date values, consider that the first two methods need conversions to/from strings, while you can easily use bind variables with date variables with no need to cast; for example:

```
declare
    vSQL    varchar2(100);
    vVar    date;
    vNum    number;
begin    
    vSQL := 'select count(*) from dual where trunc(sysdate) = :SOME_VAR';
    vVar := trunc(sysdate);
    --
    execute immediate vSQL into vNum using vVar;
    dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || vNum);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to use parameters.

But, if you want to do this by substituting values in the string, then define the string with the single quotes.  In SQL, you do this by doubling the single quote:

```
l_query := 'select sum(rec_count) from mt_table_status where table_id = 8942 and ref_d = ''<REF_D>''';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use to_date function to convert your (as I think string) ref_d parameter to date

```
declare
l_query varchar2(1024) := 'select sum(rec_count) from mt_table_status where table_id = 8942 and ref_d = <REF_D>'; 
ref_d varchar2(100) := '09.12.16';
begin
 l_query := replace(l_query,'<REF_D>','to_date('''||ref_d||''',''dd.mm.yy'')');
 dbms_output.put_line(l_query);
end;
```

output:

```
select sum(rec_count) from mt_table_status where table_id = 8942 and ref_d = to_date('09.12.16','dd.mm.yy')
```

Comment: I tried this.. it is trying to execute ref_d = to_date('09.12.16','dd.mm.yy') with the whole to_date('09.12.16','dd.mm.yy') as a string..

Comment: Use third code section (with variable binding) in @Aleksej answer, dynamic SQL not suitable for your case, each new value of date variable will cause to recompile SQL, note that compilation is not cheap operation, probably, it will take more time then SQL execution itself.